# getContentResolver() is not working

Tags: java, android

I have a class name `MyPhoneStateListener`. Here, I want to use `getContentResolver`, but there is some problem in the class. It's not my main activity.

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver()
         .query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, Calls.DATE +" desc");
```

Comment: Be more specific.  *What* about it isn't working?

Comment: MyPhoneStateListener is a custom class?

Comment: if (isPhoneCalling) {

                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
 public void run() {
 String[] projection = new String[]{Calls.NUMBER};
 Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, Calls.DATE +" desc");
                }
}
       
here "Cursor cur = getContentResolver()
         .query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, Calls.DATE +" desc");" line shows error & that is "The method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}"

Comment: yes this is custom class.  Marco Acierno

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `getContentResolver` inside another class which doesn't extends `Activity`/`Service` you should have a [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) object.

Inside your `MyPhoneStateListener` class, in your constructor ask for a `Context` and save it, then when you need the `content resolver` use `context.getContentResolver()`

Example:

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener {
 private Context context;
 public MyPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
   this.context = context;
 }

 public void someMethod() {
    Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver()
     .query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, Calls.DATE +" desc");
 }
}
```

Comment: yes , but in main activity "MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();"  what kind of parameter i will pass through in this..??

Comment: It depends on where you create the object, if it's inside your activity `MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener(this);` is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Cursor cur = this.getActivity().getContentResolver()
.query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, Calls.DATE +" desc");

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).